# After upgrading to Cocoapods 0.38 Build failsdue to library not found

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I just upgraded Cocoapods and ran a pod install. after doing a hard clean and build I'm getting the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-HHRouter clang: error: 
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried removing every reference to HHRouter and pulling the pod. It moved on to give me an error about another pod.

```
Here is what my podfile looks like:
platform :ios, '8.0'

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'JDStatusBarNotification'
pod 'HHRouter', '~> 0.1'
pod 'ViewDeck', '2.2.11'
pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
pod 'MagicalRecord'
pod 'RSKImageCropper', '1.0.0'
pod 'UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout'
pod 'FLAnimatedImage', '~> 1.0'
pod 'CRToast', '~> 0.0.7'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: getting same error after updating to pods 0.38. Did you find solution?

Comment: Nope, Although 0.38.1 is out now and I get a different issue. I get the a "Use of unresolved identifier '(every pod)'"

Comment: I am back to the original error with 0.38.2

Comment: getting this error as well, downgrading to 0.37.2 fixed it for now.

Comment: @Jeremiah - you got any fix? I also facing similar issue with this stupid update.

Comment: nope. I downgraded to 0.37.2 for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted all the settings behind Other Linker Flags, except $(inherited), and it went well.